# Hibernate don't create my tables in the database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

In my spring project, I have a service class to create my database and tables. After create the database (which is being done successfully), this method is called:

```
public void create_tables(String maquina, String usuario, String senha) {
    System.out.println("create_tables");
    create_properties(maquina, usuario, senha);

    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileInputStream( "database.properties" );
        props.load(fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    config.setProperties(props);

    try {
        String url = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,senha);
        SchemaExport schema = new SchemaExport(config, conn);
        schema.create(true, true);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    insert_default_values();
}
```

But, despite in the Eclipse console display that the schema was exported successfully, no table is created in my database.

Anyone can see what's wrong here?

**UPDATE**

database.properties

```
#propriedades
#Sat May 10 12:52:57 BRT 2014
jdbc.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost\:5432/horario
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=false
jdbc.user=<<my database user>>
jdbc.Classname=org.postgresql.Driver
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
jdbc.pass=<<my password>>
```

HibernateConfig.java -> https://github.com/klebermo/webapp_horario_livre/blob/master/src/com/horariolivre/resources/HibernateConfig.java

Entity classes -> https://github.com/klebermo/webapp_horario_livre/tree/master/src/com/horariolivre/entity

Dao classes -> https://github.com/klebermo/webapp_horario_livre/tree/master/src/com/horariolivre/dao

Comment: What is it in this code snippet that creates the tables?

Comment: SchemaExport schema = new SchemaExport(config, conn);
schema.create(true, true);

Comment: Could you edit your question and include at least a sample of what's in the file "database.properties"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding following code snippet:

```
config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.Atributo.class);
config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.Autorizacao.class);
...
```

Is this what you are looking for?